# insertNewObjectForEntityForName could not locate entity (Swift)

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, swift

I am trying to port a working CoreData application to Swift. This code fails:

```
    let moc = self.context
    NSLog("Entities: \(moc.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel.entitiesByName.allKeys)")
    let obj = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("School",
        inManagedObjectContext:moc)
```

The `NSLog` output is this:

```
2014-06-11 11:23:51.634 WYBData[18480:303] Entities [Address, Contact, Hospital, Person, Place, School]
```

So even though the log indicates there is an entity called `School`, which I assume means the `NSManagedObjectContext` is correctly set up, I still get this error:

```
2014-06-11 11:23:55.338 WYBData[18480:303] +entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'School' in this model.
2014-06-11 11:23:55.340 WYBData[18480:303] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c05725c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8f274e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreData                            0x00007fff89b20a19 +[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] + 201
3   WYBData                             0x00000001000171f3 _TFC7WYBData12WYBXmlParser7executefS0_FRGSqCSo7NSError_Sb + 2403
4   WYBData                             0x000000010000ea4a _TFC7WYBData11WYBMainView2gofS0_FPSs9AnyObject_T_ + 1642
5   WYBData                             0x000000010000ead2 _TToFC7WYBData11WYBMainView2gofS0_FPSs9AnyObject_T_ + 66
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff91d97260 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 327
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff91d970de -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86
8   AppKit                              0x00007fff91de3c4d -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 128
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff91dfd655 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 2316
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff91dfca27 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 487
11  AppKit                              0x00007fff91dfc13d -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 706
12  AppKit                              0x00007fff91d7da58 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 11296
13  AppKit                              0x00007fff91d1c5d4 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 2021
14  AppKit                              0x00007fff91b6ca19 -[NSApplication run] + 646
15  AppKit                              0x00007fff91b577a3 NSApplicationMain + 940
16  WYBData                             0x000000010000a9ed top_level_code + 109
17  WYBData                             0x000000010000aa2a main + 42
18  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8bf085fd start + 1
19  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
```

I can correctly create an `Address` entity, but none of the others. Even this is strange because `Address` is a sub-entity of `Contact` yet attempting to create `Contact` results in the same error above.

What am I missing?

EDIT:

I temporarily removed `Address` from my Core Data model, and can now create `Contact` but nothing else. So it seems that I can only create whatever is the first entity (alphabetically) defined in the model. Does this sound like a bug, or could my `NSManagedObjectModel` be corrupted somehow?

Comment: What's happen when you use println() instead NSLog() ?

Comment: Thanks @Areal-17, I get exactly the same output as NSLog()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else who encounters the same problem: the issue was my `.xcdatamodeld` file. It must have been corrupted somehow because I created a new file and exactly re-created my data model and now it works. I cannot see any difference between the two files (at least in the Xcode Core Data model editor).

My data model is shared between an iOS and OS-X project (the OS-X application prepares the data for the iOS app). I wondered if there was any difference in the `.xcdatamodeld` files created for iOS compared with OS-X.

Comment: I have the same problem. I had a quick look at the file format of the model file. I can't see any difference on first view. Did you change anything else when you re-created the file?

Comment: @WizardofKneup I tried to exactly recreated the model file. I just double-checked using diff on the contents. Some of the attributes in the XML are in a different order (making the diff harder to check!), but the only noticeable difference that I can see is that I inadvertently changed a decimal to a double, and in the new version I marked fewer attributes as optional. There is no obvious difference that would cause the error.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Surely this is a bug in XCode/CoreData. Have you reported this to Apple? @WizardofKneup

Comment: It's an old thread, but I encountered a similar issue, apparently the presence of the .xccurrentversion inside the .xcdatamodeld bundle was causing the "corruption".