# NSFetchRequest could not locate an NSEntityDescription with Swift, Core Data

Tags: cocoa, core-data, swift

I'm having a problem with Swift throwing an exception when trying to run countForFetchRequest() on one of my Core Data models. I've got a workaround, but it's horrible and I'm hoping there's a better way.

Here's the relevant chunk of the data model:
[image: data model screenshot]

Here's the code that throws the exception:

```
// Returns true if at least one object of type entityName with the value queryValue in the attribute
// attributeName exists in context context.
func objectWithAttrValueExists (attributeName: String, queryValue: AnyObject, entityName: NSString, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Bool {
    let allEntities = context.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel.entitiesByName
    // Some debugging print statements to see what NSEntityDescriptions exist.
    for key in allEntities.keys {
        println(key as String)
    }
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
    let attributeFilter = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", argumentArray: [attributeName, queryValue])
    request.predicate = attributeFilter
    var error = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?>()
    let count = context.countForFetchRequest(request, error: error) // <- Exception here.
    if count <= 0 {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

You can see I've got some debugging print statements in there; the output from them is:

```
FixtureParameterType
FixtureParameterCategory
Fixture
FixtureParameter
```

And then the exception raised is: `NSFetchRequest could not locate an NSEntityDescription for entity name 'Fixture'` (but 'Fixture' is getting printed out in the print statement above).

Here's the horrible workaround: I grab the keys from the dictionary of NSEntityDescriptions, iterate through them, and then manually assign the relevant NSEntityDescription to the NSFetchRequest. I did find this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440927/swift-core-data-on-ios7-device-entityforname-on-second-entity-is-nil) which suggests using an NSString instead of a String, but that doesn't make a difference; I get the same exception either way.

```
func objectWithAttrValueExists (attributeName: String, queryValue: AnyObject, entityName: String, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Bool {
    let allEntities = context.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel.entitiesByName
    for key in allEntities.keys {
        println(key as String)
    }
    // I would expect this to work, but it doesn't.
    //var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
    // This works but is horrible.
    var request = NSFetchRequest()
    for key in allEntities.keys {
        let strkey = key as String
        if strkey == entityName {
            request.entity = allEntities[key] as NSEntityDescription
        }
    }
    let attributeFilter = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", argumentArray: [attributeName, queryValue])
    request.predicate = attributeFilter
    var error = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?>()
    let count = context.countForFetchRequest(request, error: error) // <- Works!
    if count <= 0 {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
```

I tried doing it this way because I noticed that the values in `allEntities` are instances of `_PFEncodedString` which I thought might be screwing up the dictionary hashing. The fact that my workaround works makes me think that's correct, but if that's true then I don't know how anyone else has ever managed to get Core Data working in Swift.

This is driving me nuts -- any help appreciated.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate; the first code snippet is already using the workaround suggested in that thread, which is to use an NSString.

Comment: I've solved the problem and it wasn't related to the NSString issue; it appears to have been a corrupted .xcdatamodel file as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160619/insertnewobjectforentityforname-could-not-locate-entity-swift). Recreating an identical .xcdatamodel from scratch solved the problem, regardless of whether the entity name is passed as a String on NSString. I can't answer my own question, apparently because it's marked as a duplicate, so could you remove the duplicate marking or change it the correct solution?

Answer (score 0):

Although already mentioned to use NSString as entity name, just again.

I had the same problem and solved it by

```
NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName as NSString)
```

This error occurs only on the device, not in simulator.

Comment: Thanks, but the entityName is already being passed as an NSString, see the first code snippet I posted. I finally solved the problem, this fixed it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160619/insertnewobjectforentityforname-could-not-locate-entity-swift .